# new className().methodName(); VS className ref = new className();

Tags: java

I came across a code which my colleague uses inside an `eventListner`, which is :

```
private void someActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new className().methodName(); //public class and public void methodName()
}
```

I was pretty sure that :

```
private void someActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    className ref = new className(); //public class and public void 
    ref.methodName();
}
```

is the better option than his, as the previous method instantiates a `class` every time it is called.
Am I wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated, Please correct me if I am wrong
*.*

Comment: "as the previous method instantiates a class every time it is called" so does the latter method...

Comment: Both codes do the same.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes it is. but we can use the `reference` further without instantiating it again and again. Isn't it?

Comment: @Jens So what may be the differences between them?

Comment: @mustangDC There is no difference.

Comment: Both samples are instantiating new object every time ...

Comment: The first code-sample does not even compile! - As long as className.methodName is not a static nested class...

Comment: Yes, he created those as static to access it from another class. @DaniEll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both do the same thing, however one of them (the first) is 1 line shorter.

Your approach is usually recommended when you need to go through more than 2-3 objects, so `new Foo().getBar1().getBar2().doStuff()` is usually not recommended since it can degrade into spaghetti code and hinder the understandability of the code.

Comment: So except `reusing` the class reference afterwards, there is no difference memory wise?

Comment: @mustangDC: No, in both cases the object created will be garbage collected the moment execution steps out of the method scope.

Comment: What about : new Thread(){public void run(){}}.start(); ??? Sorry bcoz its a comment, so cannot format it.

Comment: Yes this will create a thread( :-P ) but i want to know what it is called?

Comment: @Aman: You can use: `new Thread("myThreadName"){...`, as per the Java Docs.

Comment: @npinti actually I want to know the technical name of this. For e.g.: temporary thread or something like this.

Comment: @Aman: Oh I understand. I do not think it has a particular name :).

Answer (score 4):

The **first code-sample** instantiates a new *Object* of Type *className.methodName*.
For this to work, *methodName* has to be a static nested class of Type *className*.
**Attention:** This could as well be a typo. Did you mean *new className().methodName()*?

The **second sample** creates a new instance of *className* and calls its method *methodName*.

Some example code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test.test(); // instantiates the inner class

        Test t = new Test(); // instantiates Test
        t.test(); // calls method #test of Test-instance
    }

    public String test() {
        return "Test";
    }

    public static class test {

    }

}
```

In order to judge what's the best solution your example does not give enought information. Is the method some static utility code or is an instance of *className* useful? It depends...

Comment: The first one is like `new Car().mustangGT();` and the 2nd one is like the basic what we have learnt

Comment: no, the first one does not call a method *mustangGT*! it instantiates a new Car.mustangGT which has to be a **static nested class** - one could say mustangGT **is a** Car - mustangGt is **not a method of** Car

Comment: `Car` is a `public class` and `mustangGT()` is a `public static` method : what I am taking about

Comment: Then check your first code sample, it does not compile when mustangGT is a static method!

Comment: Yes you are correct, it only works for static methods. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Check @Harsh Poddar's edit, two parenthesis change "everything"!

Comment: I edited the question to terminate any further confusion :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Whenever an object is instantiated but is not assigned a reference variable, it is called anonymous object instantiation.

With anonymous object you can call it's instance method also:

```
new className().methodName();
```

In your case this is the anonymous object which doesn't have reference variable.

In the statements:

```
className ref = new className();
ref.methodName();
```

`ref` is the reference variable to hold the className object, so you can call instance methods of className on `ref` variable.

The benefit of using anonymous notation is, if you want to do only limited (may be calling single method and so on..) operation with the underlying object the it is a good approach. But if you needs to perform more operation with the underlying object then you need to keep that object in a reference variable so that you can use that reference to perform multiple operations with that object.

Regarding the performance there are not much difference as both are in methods scope, as soon as method completes both the objects are valid candidates for the garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Both the methods instantiates a class in the code. If you want to reuse the class object every time the method is called, you can declare it as a member of the class where the method resides. For eg:

```
class AnotherClass{
    private ClassName ref;

    AnotherClass(){
          ref = new ClassName()
    }

    private void someActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        ref.methodName();
    }
}
```

This way, everytime your method `someActionPerformed` is called on an object of `AnotherClass`, it will reuse the `ref` object instead of instantiating it everytime.

---

About the edit,

```
public class ClassName {
    static class InnerClass{
        // A static inner class
    }
    public void methodName() {
        // A method
    }
}

class AnotherClass{
    private void someActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        // This creates an instance of the inner class `InnerClass`
        new ClassName.InnerClass(); 
        // However I believe, you wanted to do:
        new ClassName().methodName();
    }    
}
```

Comment: So I guess except `reusing` class reference afterwards, there is no difference memory wise?

Comment: @mustangDC no, not really. The only difference you may find is, just how npinti said, in the readability of the code. Other than that, there is no significant difference.

Comment: We could also do `new Car().mustangGT();` right ? Where `Car` is a class and `mustangGT()` is a method

Comment: the code `new className.methodName(); ` will work if `methodName` is actually a static inner class. Though I believe, you wanted to write `new className().methodName(); `

Comment: ^that means that you want to instantiate the class `className` by calling the constructor with no params and then call the method `methodName` on the instantiated class

Answer (score 0):

new className.methodName(); --> if you are using this convention in your code then calling another method name will result to different object's method name and you lose your values.

className ref = new className();
    ref.methodName();  -> here you are creating a reference and make assiging a newly created object and you are calling the method's on it. Suppose if you want to call another method on the same object it will helps.

The first approach they will mostly use for listenere which is anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

Both options create a new Class every time they are called. The advantage of the second over the first option would be if you wanted to reuse that class later in the method.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a little bit more understandable code for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31607565/1159404) provided by DaniEll

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test.test(); // instantiates the inner class
        Test t = new Test(); // instantiates Test
        t.test(); // calls method #test of Test-instance
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Outer class");
    }

    public static class test {
        public test() {
            System.out.println("Inner class");
        }
    }
}
```