# Java bad practice doing: new... ().doSomething()?

Tags: java, constructor, static-methods, object-construction

I just saw a piece of code that had some classes with only one method. I picked an examples:

```
public class TempDirCleanupProcess {
  public void cleanup(final File directory) {} 
}
```

Then, later on in the code the method was called the following way:

```
new TempDirCleanupProcess().cleanup(tempDir);
```

Now I am wondering if this is a bad practice because I have seen such "behavior" only with static methods before.
Any oppinions on that?

Comment: With non static methods, every call your TempDirCleanupProcess is constructed anew. If it happens often or it takes much resources you should consider injecting a cleanup service. Static methods are class methods, so they do not have this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new className().methodName(); VS className ref = new className();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607335/new-classname-methodname-vs-classname-ref-new-classname)

Comment: The difference is that static methods cannot be overridden, whereas non-static methods can.

Comment: @MCEmperor but if you're writing `new TempDirCleanupProcess()`, you're getting that exact class' methods, not an override.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, *that* part doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Using static methods is not object oriented, introduces hidden hard coupling, makes testing a nightmare and is considered by many OOP purists an anti-pattern. personally I would only use static methods as named constructors.

Comment: with "new" keyword the constructor method will be called recursively over all subclasses until object. It will also allocate memory for your object on Heap. It is an expensive operation for just calling a method.

Comment: One may say it's too broad, or not clear enough, but it's definitely not opinion-based. I am voting to reopen it.

Comment: To clairify this: I want to know if this is any Software engineering related Bad practice mit how anyone of you would handle this!

Comment: @ItFreak what did you mean by "anyone of you would handle this"? If you can rewrite that piece, we recommend you go with a static method.

Comment: Yea thats what I meant:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it could be refactored into a class with a static method. It would obviate the need for creating an instance every time one needs to call the method. In this particular case with no additional context given, a static method would be a nicer solution.

However, don't forget a class can hold a state and a single method may change that state and return a reference to the current object.

```
public class Builder {
  // state

  public Builder buildPart(T part) { 
      // update the state
      return this;
  } 

}
```

It would resemble a variation of the builder pattern and make sense.

```
return new Builder();
return new Builder().buildPart(partA);
return new Builder().buildPart(partA).buildPart(partB);
```

I can also think of an *extremely* poor design where `this` would be leaked out from `cleanup`, so a reference to that `new TempDirCleanupProcess()` wouldn't be lost after the line is executed.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a standard static method, but we don't see all the details

So maybe when you are creating the object you are also creating instance members that are used in the method `cleanup` and you must create the object in order to make them available

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to have a Directory class like such

```
Directory temp = new Directory('path/to/file');
temp.cleanup()
```

This also allows you to inherit the Directory class in some other class that requires all of these utility functions.

That being said, a utility function in a class like yours should be static.

Comment: It must not be static because it would  introduce hard & hidden coupling and will make testing a nightmare.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev you could use `PowerMockito.mockStatic`.

Comment: Of course you can, but if you have to cheat, then your design is shit.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Are you saying the method itself would be a testing nightmare or that using the method in other code would be a testing nightmare? If the former, it shouldn't be any harder to test than testing an instance method—assuming the method is effectively self-contained. If the latter, you could always abstract the call to the method, allowing you to mock it at the call site (though this may not be acceptable/desirable).

Comment: I'm saying that using static methods is bad practice. The simplest real world case is introducing a hidden dependency to `System.getProperty` or the like - imagine a test that depends on system properties and it fails because some other test had set some property. `you could always abstract the call to the method` -> Of course you can abstract it using an interface, but then it's not a static method anymore, is it ? Then you have a polymorphic call, not a call to static method. You have a dependency to an abstraction, not a concrete class.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev are you saying that _all_ static methods are bad (including `Math.abs`, `Collections.unmodifiableMap`, etc) or just a specific type of static method? If it's the latter, what would make a static method bad?

Comment: IMO almost all static methods are bad. For instance in Rust you do not have `Math.abs`, but call `123.abs()` on the number itself (same as min/max/sqrt, etc) `Collections.unmodifiableMap` is a named constructor, which is the only valid use for a static method.  The issue here is not with the method itself, but the lack of real unmodifiable collections(see the rust-lang approach). Static methods are bad because they are not object oriented - they are procedural code and are born from procedural way of thinking.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException This guy has a very nice blog about OOP (although it's very radical at times): https://www.yegor256.com/ He has very nice articles about oop, static methods and the getter/setter antipaterns.